# Dictionary with value for key as another dicitonary python

Tags: python

Given this input dictionary :

```
from collections import defaultdict
test = defaultdict(dict)
test['ParentKey'] = {}
test['ParentKey'] = {'ChildKey1': 'Value'}
test['ParentKey'] = {'ChildKey2': 'Value'}
```

This approach seems to override the first value and the printed dicitonary is  :

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'ParentKey': {'ChildKey2': 'Value'}})
```

Is there a way to save all the new values to the child dictionary and not override them ?

Prefered output would look like this :

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'ParentKey': {'ChildKey1': 'Value','ChildKey2': 'Value'}})
```

In python 3.7

Comment: `test['ParentKey']['ChildKey1'] = 'Value'`…!?

Comment: If you don't want to override them ... then don't override them ;-) The whole point of `defaultdict` is that you can reference missing values without explicitly adding them first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After declaring `test['ParentKey']`, you can use the dictionary method `update` to add pairs to the dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
test = defaultdict(dict)
test['ParentKey'] = {}
test['ParentKey'].update({'ChildKey1': 'Value'})
test['ParentKey'].update({'ChildKey2': 'Value'})

>>> test
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'ParentKey': {'ChildKey1': 'Value', 'ChildKey2': 'Value'}})
```

Comment: The `test['ParentKey'] = {}` line is redundant for a `defaultdict`. And creating a new `dict` just to update a single value is unnecessarily inefficient.